# pyautogui.doubleClick(): Why does it work only in two try/except blocks?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have solved some issues using try/except twice running a function.

The last time it was using "pyautogui". If I try simulate a double click mouse on Windows 8.1 with  `pyautogui.doubleClick(100,100)` I have the response "PermissionError [WinError 5]".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    pg.doubleClick(1210,110)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 458, in doubleClick
    click(x, y, 2, interval, button, _pause=False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 362, in click
    platformModule._click(x, y, 'left')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 436, in _click
    _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTCLICK, x, y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 479, in _sendMouseEvent
    raise ctypes.WinError()
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado.
```

But I can solve using try/except twice:

```
try:
    pyautogui.doubleClick(1210,110)
except:
    try:
        pyautogui.doubleClick(1210,110)
    except:
        pass
```

Someone can tell me what's happening?

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a stack trace that you got if *didn't* suppress the exception. (Do you get a successful click, even if just a single click, *and* an exception thrown, in the case without this workaround?)

Comment: ...and while building a standalone reproducer (that is, a reproducer that sets up all the prerequisites to reproduce the bug on someone else's system, rather than requiring them to actually *have* something that'll catch the double click at the right location) for this might be tricky, it's going to improve your chances of getting a good answer rather significantly.

Comment: (one guess that comes to mind is that your exception is happening after the call has succeeded in *something* -- maybe, sending a single click event -- but without seeing the stack trace, how are we to know?)

Answer (score 3):

I had your problem with `pyautogui.doubleClick()` that doesn't click ...

But, in the [documentation page](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks), I saw also the keyword argument `clicks`, that you can use it like this :

```
pyautogui.click(x=87, y=227, clicks=2) # double left click on the point(x,y)
```

For me it worked ! :)